# Retrieve values from Dynamically created bootstrap forms using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am working on a project where I allow the user to create enter one/many work experience details by dynamically adding form fields on click using a Bootstrap form. But am not sure of how to retrieve the values from these forms.

```js
$(function()
    {
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
                currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
                newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

            newEntry.find('input').val('');
            controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
                .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
        }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
        {
            $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
                                        <li>
                                        <form role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('studentDashboardController/saveUserResumeDetails')?>">
                                            <div class="entry input-group col-xs-5">
                                                <input class="form-control" name="fields0[]" type="text" placeholder="Work Experience Title" />
                                                <input class="form-control" name="fields1[]" type="text" placeholder="Work Description" />
                                                <input class="col-md-6" name="fields21[]" type="text" placeholder="From(Year)" />
                                                <input class="col-md-6" name="fields22[]" type="text" placeholder="From(Month)" />
                                                <input class="col-md-6" name="fields31[]" type="text" placeholder="To(Year)" />
                                                <input class="col-md-6" name="fields32[]" type="text" placeholder="To(Month)" />
                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                                </button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        </li>
                                        <br>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
    <!--                                        <a href="--><?php //echo base_url("/index.php/studentDashboardController/saveUserResumeDetails"); ?><!--" >-->
                                                <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
    <!--                                        </a>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

I'm working with the

- CodeIgniter framework
- PHP
- MVC Architectureand

And the form above will basically be a part of my form and on submitting I call my controller `studentDashboardController`'s `saveUserResumeDetails` method. From here, I'll be calling the `userModel`'s `saveUserResumeDetails` method to store the user entered work experience detils into my `studentprofile` database table column.

The work experiences entered by the student will be stored in the following format inside the database table field.

```
work experience title - work description - 2015-08 - 2016-04, 
another work experience title - work description - 2016-03 - 2016-09, 
another work experience title - work description - 2014-10 - 2016-02,
```

**Database `studentprofile` Table**

[image: pic]

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Define a method of form like POST OR GET then for post method you can retrieve data by echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST) and for get use $_GET

Comment: @KrishnaGupta Could you please give a sample answer with reference to my form above. Thanks in advance

Comment: On your action write echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); die for debug

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller, post all data to your model:

```
$this->load->model('userModel');
$user = new userModel();
//print your post to debug, if necessary:
//print_r($this->input->post());
$user->saveUserResumeDetails($this->input->post());
```

In your model, You've got an array of each field:

```
public function saveUserResumeDetails($formData){
    foreach ($formData["fields0"] as $value) {
       echo "Filds0: $value<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this.